# How to use a column value in Pandas agg() function with df.groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this,

```
     TEST_NUM SITE_NUM     RESULT TEST_FLG                TEST_TXT UNITS LO_LIMIT HI_LIMIT
24        156        0  -0.610926        P  Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0     V       -1     -0.3
25        156        1  -0.611923        P  Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0     V       -1     -0.3
26        156        2  -0.616851        P  Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0     V       -1     -0.3
27        156        3  -0.438305        P  Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0     V       -1     -0.3
```

This is just a snippet, We have more `TEST_NUM`, `SITE_NUM` and `TEST_TXT`. The only thing to notice is, `"UNITS, LO_LIMIT and HI_LIMIT"` is common for a certain `TEST_TXT`.

So, all "**Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0**" will have same `UNITS`, `LO_LIMIT` and `HI_LIMIT`. Similarly, say, "**Continuity_PPMU ADBUS1**" will have other `UNITS, LO_LIMIT, HI_LIMIT` but they will be same for all same "**Continuity_PPMU ADBUS1**" entries.

I am using df.groupby + agg to find some statistics, like mean, max, min, percentile(25), percentile(50), percentile(75) for each TEST_TXT.

My code is like this, which works totally fine

```
    def percentile(self,n):
        def percentile_(x):
            return np.percentile(x, n)
        percentile_.__name__ = '%s%' % n
        return percentile_    

df_cpy = df.groupby(['TEST_TXT'],as_index = False)["RESULT"].agg(['count',np.mean,np.std,'min',
'max',obj.percentile(25),obj.percentile(50),obj.percentile(75)])
```

Which looks like this -

```
TEST_TXT    count   mean    std min max 25  50  75
0   Continuity_PPMU ADBUS0  40  -0.5656 0.0771  -0.6169 -0.4330 -0.6118 -0.6075 -0.5645
1   Continuity_PPMU ADBUS1  40  -0.5672 0.0771  -0.6152 -0.4343 -0.6117 -0.6103 -0.5660
2   Continuity_PPMU ADBUS2  40  -0.5668 0.0773  -0.6193 -0.4332 -0.6131 -0.6084 -0.5654
3   Continuity_PPMU ADBUS3  40  -0.5681 0.0778  -0.6186 -0.4338 -0.6143 -0.6112 -0.5664
```

The issue is, I want to have another function like obj.percentile to calculate **process capacity indices.**, and for that, I will need `LO_LIMIT` and `HI_LIMIT` value for that particular `TEST_TXT`(does not matter which one, for a certain `TEST_TXT`, all `LO_LIMIT` and `HI_LIMIT` are same).

I want something like this

```
def some_other_function(self,lo_limit,hi_limit):
    def some_other_function_(x):
        do something
    some_other_function_.__name__ = '%s%' % n
    return some_other_function_

df_cpy = df.groupby(['TEST_TXT'],as_index = False)["RESULT"].agg(['count',np.mean,np.std,'min',
'max',obj.cpl(),obj.cpk(),obj.cpu(),obj.percentile(25),obj.percentile(50),obj.percentile(75), 
obj.some_other_function(lo_limit_value_for_particular_TEST_TXT,hi_limit_value_for_particular_TEST_TXT]))
```

Can anyone help me with this, I tried a couple of things but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: what is your expected output? You have shown the input data, and *incorrect output*, but it would be helpful to have *correct output*.

Comment: @DavidErickson The statistic I have currently with me for each TEST_TXT is not wrong. mean, std, count, they all are correct. It is just that I want to have another column beside current output, but for that, I will need the LO_LIMIT, HI_LIMIT for a particular TEST_TXT in the calculation of the value of that particular column.

Comment: What is the expected output of this new column and how would you calculate it numerically? Can you give some examples of one or two rows? And you don't need to `.agg` on a specific column like `Result`. You can do so on the entire dataframe. I don't know what `process capacity indices` are , so  I would need to see the numbers to understand the calculation.

Comment: Also, I tried running your code and received this error `NameError: name 'obj' is not defined`

Comment: @DavidErickson I think it will be too domain specific. If you want to know how it is calculated, check out this link https://gist.github.com/countrymarmot/8413981, It uses standard deviation, mean of "Result" for particular TEST_TXT. Along with that, where you see usl and lsl, I want HI_LIMIT and LO_LIMIT for particular "TEST_TXT". For a unique TEST_TXT, there are 40 records, but all of them have same HI_LIMIT, LO_LIMIT and UNITS so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @DavidErickson Yes, that is because it is a part of a bigger code. Obj is the object of a class which is very big to be mentioned here, also it has nothing much to do with this part.

Comment: Okay, gotchya, I probably won't be able to help much without being able to test in myself, but you can setup your groupby like this `df.groupby(['TEST_TXT'],as_index = False).agg` instead of`df.groupby(['TEST_TXT'],as_index = False)["RESULT"].agg` . That should allow you to perform any calculations that you need all at once, but you'll need to restructure your code a little bit. Another alternative is to just do another separate groupby and then merge in the column.